# i want to make a quiz game but i have a problem

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to make biology quiz game on turkish language for my project but i have a big problem in code, this problem: when you press a true answer on true question you can't take a 1 dogrucevap point, i can't handle this code

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
x = 0
d = 0
def dogru():
      global d
      d += 1
      dLabel.config(font = (25),text=str(d))
      dLabel.place(x = 680, y=100)        
def arttir():
  global x
  x += 1
  xLabel.config(text=str(x))
  xLabel.place(x=680, y=125)  
  if x == 1: 
        soru1.destroy()
        soru2.pack()
        soru2.place(x=225,y=35)
        soru2.config(font = (70))
  if x == 2:
        soru2.destroy()
        soru3.pack()
        soru3.place(x=225,y=35)
        soru3.config(font = (70))    
  if x == 3:
        soru3.destroy()
        soru4.pack()
        soru4.place(x=225,y=35)
        soru4.config(font = (70))

master=tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Oyun")
master.geometry("800x300")

xLabel = Label(master, text=str(x))
dLabel = Label(master, text=str(d))

#sorular

#Mitoz
soru1 = Label(text = "Ana hücrenin bölünerek iki yeni hücre oluşumu.")
soru1.pack()
soru1.place(x=225,y=35)
soru1.config(font = (70))
#Mitokondri
soru2 = Label(text = "Oksijenli solunum ile ATP üretir.")
#Lizozom
soru3 = Label(text = "Hücrenin savunmasını üstlenir.")
#Ribozom
soru4 = Label(text = "Hücrenin protein sentezinde görevli olan zarsız organel.")


sorudegeri = Label(text = "question number: ")
sorudegeri.place(x=650, y=105)
dogrudegeri = Label(text = "correct answers")
dogrudegeri.place(x=650, y=80)



button1=tkinter.Button(master, text="Mitoz", command = arttir)
button1.place(x=595, y=240)
button1.config(font = (25))


button3=tkinter.Button(master, text="Mitokondri", command = arttir)
button3.place(x=505, y=200)
button3.config(font = ("44"))

button4=tkinter.Button(master, text="Lizozom", command = arttir)
button4.place(x=525, y=240)
button4.config(font = ("44"))

button5=tkinter.Button(master, text="Ribozom", command = arttir)
button5.place(x=445, y=240)
button5.config(font = ("44"))

if x == 0:
        if [button1]:
            dogru()                                    
if x == 1:
      if [button3]:
            dogru()

xLabel.pack()
dLabel.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

i want to make biology quiz game on turkish language for my project but i have a big problem in code, this problem: when you press a true answer on true question you can't gain a 1 dogrucevap point, i can't handle this damn code (i know my english is not very well :) )

Comment: What is wrong with it?.  "If you press true on a true question you get a point" sounds like it's working

Comment: the problem it, this code its not get a point when you a press true button on true question (i said my english is not very well I am changing my text immediately
)

Comment: Can you please provide minimalistic code that works. We don't want to go through the whole code trying to find the source of the problem.

Comment: To expand on what @TheLizzard says, start with making the project work for a single question, if you can't do that, we may be able to help debug it with you more easily.

Comment: You should also learn how to use loops and lists to avoid all that repetition.

Comment: i edited code, I guess right now this code is more minimalist by the way thanks for your interest

Comment: I want him to get points after answering the correct question correctly, but that's all I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimalistic rewrite of your game that uses a list of questions and loops to arrange the buttons. I figured the idea of your game is to choose the correct answer for each question.

```
import tkinter
import random

questions = [
    {"answer": "Mitoz", "question": "Ana hücrenin bölünerek iki yeni hücre oluşumu."},
    {"answer": "Fenotip", "question": "Hücre zarı ve çekirdeğin arasında bulunur."},
    {"answer": "Modifikasyon", "question": "Canlılarda çevrenin etkisiyle meydana gelen ve kalıtsal olmayan özelliklerdir."},
    {"answer": "Baskın Gen", "question": "Anne ve babadan aktarılarak aynı fiziksel özelliği etkiler."},
    {"answer": "Mutasyon", "question": "Bir canlının genomu içindeki DNA ya da RNA diziliminde meydana gelen kalıcı değişmelerdir."},
    {"answer": "Virus", "question": "Sadece canlı hücreleri enfekte edebilir."},
    {"answer": "Bakteri", "question": "Tek hücreli mikroorganizma grubudur."},
    {"answer": "Hücre", "question": "Bir canlının yapısal ve işlevsel özellikler gösterebilen en küçük birimidir."},
    {"answer": "Mayoz", "question": "Oksijenli solunum ile ATP üretir."},
    {"answer": "Mitokondri", "question": "Hücrenin savunmasını üstlenir."},
    {"answer": "Lizozom", "question": "Hücrenin protein sentezinde görevli olan zarsız organel."},
    {"answer": "Ribozom", "question": "Bir kromozomun belirli bir kısmını oluşturan nükleotid dizisidir."},
    {"answer": "Gen", "question": "Fiziksel özelliklerimizi etkileyen genler."},
    {"answer": "DNA", "question": "Kalıtsal özelliklerimizi taşıyan genler."},
    {"answer": "Sitoplazma", "question": "Eşeyli ürüyen canlılarda bulunan hücre türü."},
    {"answer": "Genotip", "question": "Bilgiyi uzun süreli saklar"},
]


def update_ui():
    score_label.config(text=str(score))
    num_questions_label.config(text="%d/%d" % (question_index + 1, len(questions)))
    question_label.config(text=get_current_question()["question"])
    # TODO: don't crash when the game is finished


random.shuffle(questions)
master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Oyun")

question_index = 0
score = 0

score_label = tkinter.Label(master)
num_questions_label = tkinter.Label(master)
question_label = tkinter.Label(master)


def get_current_question():
    return questions[question_index]


def choose_answer(answer):
    global score, question_index
    if get_current_question()["answer"] == answer:
        score += 1
        question_index += 1
    update_ui()


def make_answer_button(parent, answer):
    return tkinter.Button(parent, text=answer, command=lambda: choose_answer(answer))


num_questions_label.pack()
score_label.pack()
question_label.pack()

answer_frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
answer_frame.pack()

for i, answer in enumerate(sorted([q["answer"] for q in questions])):
    y, x = divmod(i, 3)  # figure out grid coordinates
    make_answer_button(answer_frame, answer).grid(row=y, column=x)

update_ui()  # initial update
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: hahahah mister thats a very very good I did not know what to say thank you !!, you saved my erasmus project!